# Sending an email exclusively from FreeMarker

Tags: templates, velocity, freemarker

I'm trying to send an email using a FreeMarker (.ftl) template. I have an example of something I want in FreeMarker already completed in Velocity:

```
#set ($from = $var.getClass().forName('javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress').newInstance())
#set ($VOID = $from.setAddress($emailAddress))
#set ($VOID = $from.setPersonal($fullName))

#set ($to = $var.getClass().forName('javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress').newInstance())
#set ($VOID = $to.setAddress("admin@gmail.com"))

#set ($mailMessage = $var.getClass().forName('com.test.mail.service.MailMessage').newInstance())
#set ($VOID = $mailMessage.setBody("Sample Text."))
#set ($VOID = $mailMessage.setHTMLFormat('true'))
#set ($VOID = $mailMessage.setFrom($from))
#set ($VOID = $mailMessage.setSubject("Sample Subject"))
#set ($VOID = $mailMessage.setTo($to))

#set ($mailService = $serviceLocator.findService('com.test.mail.service.MailService'))

#set ($VOID = $mailService.sendEmail($mailMessage))
```

My major problem is getting a new instance of a class (i.e., `javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress`). Is there a way do get a new instance of this class so I can use it? If not, how can I send an email exclusively from a FreeMarker template, similar to how the Velocity template did it?